# InfoPath forms viewer web part

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I'd like to write a SharePoint web part that would display InfoPath forms and have some additional functionallity. Does anyone know how to implement the "forms display" part of the web part???

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for making this community wiki? That feature is for discussion-type questions and people motivated by reputation are less likely to answer you. See clarification at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow

Comment: If they are web info path forms in a form library, they have a url, so it can be implemented with an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the XmlFormView control in Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Server.Controls. The control has all the properties you need to display the right form, such as:

```
XmlFormView.XsnLocation
XmlFormView.XmlLocation
XmlFormView.SaveLocation
```

This should help:
[Hosting the InfoPath 2007 Form Editing Environment in a Custom Web Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa701078.aspx)